# Can I use xpath from body directly in bean method call?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using this XML DSL in Camel at the moment:

```
<route>
    ...
    <setProperty propertyName="inputFilepath">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/tla:InputType/tla:inputFilepath/text()</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <setProperty propertyName="outputFilepath">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">/tla:InputType/tla:outputFilepath/text()</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <bean ref="bean1" method="process(${property.inputFilepath},${property.outputFilepath})"/>
    ...
```

But I would like to use something closer to:

```
<route>
    ...
    <bean ref="bean1" method="process(xpath('/tla:InputType/tla:inputFilepath/text()'),xpath('/tla:InputType/tla:inputFilepath/text()'))"/>
    ...
```

Is there something that I could use that is less cluttered than my current route?

I don't want to use @XPath inside the bean because I don't want dependencies on the external environment embedded in the bean class.

I did look at OGNL, which I believe can be used in a Simple expression, so something along the lines of:

```
<bean ref="bean1" method="process(${body.InputType.inputFilepath},${body.InputType.inputFilepath})"/>
```

or

```
<bean ref="bean1" method="process(${body.tla:InputType.tla:inputFilepath},${body.tla:InputType.tla:inputFilepath})"/>
```

but neither worked.

I also suspect that I should be using headers instead of properties, because the values only have to last until the method call, and not for the rest of the exchange.  I'd be interested to hear comments on that too.

Thanks for ideas on improving this!

Comment: I haven't had chance to try this but have you tried generating the method name using the Simple language? http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Comment: The ${property.inputFilepath} is written in Simple.
The problem is that Simple doesn't have syntax for executing xpath.  I did look at OGNL - I'll edit the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the properties and sending it as method parameters you can perform a XSL in the incoming payload and then the call the bean. This will reduce setting the properties and calling the bean with the property values. The first line will be XSL transformation and then you can call a processor. The processor will be able to get the needed values from the incoming exchange, which is the result of the transformation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would replace the two setProperty elements with a processor.  Would that be a custom Java bean processor that reads the values from the payload and creates the two property values for the method call?
What would the XSL transformation do?

Comment: You can check my new reply

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing multiple set properties you can use an XSL. In the next step in the bean you can transform the xml to a pojo using a xstream or jaxb parser. By this way you can avoid performing xpath in the bean or in the camel-context.xml.

step 1.FileTransform.XSL (example)




step 2. In the Bean / Processor
Create a Pojo called FileProp with inputFilePath, outputFilePath as String(s).Use a parser like Xstream and convert the incoming XML to POJO (using fromXML method)
http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html
http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html
Now you have the POJO which you can use with ease in the bean

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is interesting, but feels like quite a heavyweight solution for my requirement.  I was looking for something that was simpler to read in the route.